# Picker view not selecting first object

Tags: ios, select, button, uipickerview, swift4

My code right now has a picker view that places a word on a textfield. The problem is that the user must change the word on the picker view for it to work. I added some more info below my picture.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController , UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet var tx: UITextField!

    let animals = ["lion", "Dog","JUDO"]
    var pickerview = UIPickerView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib

        pickerview.delegate = self
        pickerview.dataSource = self
        tx.inputView = pickerview
        let toolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height, width: view.bounds.width, height: 44))

        var items = [UIBarButtonItem]()


        items.append( UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(doneAction)) )
        toolbar.items = items
        tx.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
    }
    @objc func doneAction(){

        tx.resignFirstResponder()
        view.endEditing(true)

    }
    public func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    public func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return animals.count
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return  animals[row]
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        tx.text = animals[row]

    }
}
```

[image: picker view with default value selected; text field is empty]

If I hit the Done button, nothing is transferred. I would have to scroll down from "Lion" to "Dog", then back to "Lion" for "Lion" to be transferred. I just want to hit the Done button and have "Lion" to be transferred.

Answer (score 0):

The value of the picker view **does not change initially**. You should make the first element of your array the text of the text field in `viewDidLoad`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    [...]

    tx.text = animals.first
}
```

Comment: is there anyway you could arrange the picker view to always resort to having lion appear first no matter what?

Comment: @SamBurns I'm afraid I don't understand. The picker view currently shows "lion" as the first element.

Comment: If I select dog. Then click on the textfield dog will be the first thing that appears or what the user is currently selecting

Comment: @SamBurns If you want to select a particular row, use the `selectRow(_:component:animated:)` method, like this: `picker.selectRow([row number, 0 in your case], inComponent: [component number, 0 in your case], animated: false)`

Comment: Make your `animals` property mutable, that is `var animals = ...`. Every time you tap the done button, remove the selected item and insert it at index zero (0) of the `animals` property. Then, reload the `pickerView`.

Answer (score 0):

If you like to get value of picker on click on done button you should use `pickerview.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)` to get current value chosen in picker view . If you open and dismiss picker without scrolling then `func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)` will not be called . So your code need to be changed as below

```
@objc func doneAction(){

        let selectedIndex = pickerview.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
        tx.text = animals[selectedIndex]
        tx.resignFirstResponder()
        view.endEditing(true)

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try Following Solution

```
 @objc func doneAction(){

    tx.resignFirstResponder()

    // get first index value of array if tx is empty
    if (tx.text?.isEmpty)! {
       tx.text = self.animals.first
    }

    view.endEditing(true)

}
```

Comment: @YogeshBharate It perfectly works....I have checked with my own demo...